# Pandas GroupBy and Calculate Z-Score

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame([[1, 10, 14], [1, 12, 14], [1, 20, 12], [1, 25, 12], [2, 18, 12], [2, 30, 14], [2, 4, 12], [2, 10, 14]], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])

    A   B   C
0   1   10  14
1   1   12  14
2   1   20  12
3   1   25  12
4   2   18  12
5   2   30  14
6   2   4   12
7   2   10  14
```

My goal is to get the z-scores of column B, relative to their groups by column A and C. I know I can calculate the mean and standard deviation of each group

```
test.groupby(['A', 'C']).mean()    
        B
A   C   
1   12  22.5
    14  11.0
2   12  11.0
    14  20.0

test.groupby(['A', 'C']).std()
        B
A   C   
1   12  3.535534
    14  1.414214
2   12  9.899495
    14  14.142136
```

Now for every item in column B I want to calculate it's z-score based off of these means and standard deviations. So the first result would be (10 - 11) / 1.41. I feel like there has to be a way to do this without too much complexity but I've been stuck on how to proceed. Let me know if anyone can point me in the right direction or if I need to clarify anything!

Answer (score 16):

Do with `transform`

```
Mean=test.groupby(['A', 'C']).B.transform('mean')    
Std=test.groupby(['A', 'C']).B.transform('std')
```

Then

```
(test.B - Mean) / Std
```

---

One function `zscore` from `scipy`

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
test.groupby(['A', 'C']).B.transform(lambda x : zscore(x,ddof=1))
Out[140]: 
0   -0.707107
1    0.707107
2   -0.707107
3    0.707107
4    0.707107
5    0.707107
6   -0.707107
7   -0.707107
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Ok Show my number tie out hehe

```
(test.B - Mean) / Std ==test.groupby(['A', 'C']).B.transform(lambda x : zscore(x,ddof=1))
Out[148]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

Comment: can you manually show your output is correct. The zscore looks strange.  series-series.mean()/series.std() grouped by A and C

Comment: @GoldenLion what you mean ..manually ?

Comment: show your numbers tie out.  The repeating number looks suspicious

Comment: @GoldenLion Good luck

Comment: did you use the given dataframe above or did you use your own test data

Comment: @GoldenLion I am using the given data ...did you try from your end ? just try it

Comment: df=pd.DataFrame([[1, 10, 14], [1, 12, 14], [1, 20, 12], [1, 25, 12], [2, 18, 12], [2, 30, 14], [2, 4, 12], [2, 10, 14]], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(df.groupby(['A','B']).transform(zscore))   my code generates NaN for C zscores

Comment: @GoldenLion man are you sure you were using my code ? or you have a new question about your own code ? `test.groupby(['A', 'C']).B.transform(lambda x : zscore(x,ddof=1))` this is my code

Comment: your results don't match mine

Comment: @GoldenLion If you can not match the first method I provided , then most likely you have some glitch in your code which yield the different result

Comment: @GoldenLion, the method above by BENY is correct.  The reason why the z-scores are all the same 0.707107 (whether positive or negative) is because the sample df posted by the original user contained only two "results" for each groupby.  Put another way, each groupby of 'A' and 'C' resulted in only two rows.  When the average of the rows is taken and then a z-score is calculated, it will come to the same 0.707107 (one being positive, the other being negative).  To see that BENY's code is correct, simply add another row to the original df like [1, 15, 14] and you will see that z-scores change.