# Pandas How to group by month and year using dt

Tags: python, pandas

I am just wondering how to group by both year and month using pandas.series.dt.

The code below groups by just year, but how would I add a further filter to group by month as well.

```
Data = {'Date':['21.10.1999','30.10.1999','02.11.1999','17.08.2000','09.10.2001','14.07.2000'],'X': [10,20,30,40,50,60],'Y': [5,10,15,20,25,30]}

df = pd.DataFrame(Data)

#Convert to pandas date time
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

#Obtain dataframe dtypes
print(df.dtypes)

print(df)
print(df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year).sum())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> am just wondering how to group by both year and month using pandas.series.dt.

You can pass [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and 
[`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) with `rename` to `groupby`, new columns are not necessary:

```
print(df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.year.rename('y'), df['Date'].dt.month.rename('m')]).sum())
          X   Y
y    m         
1999 2   30  15
     10  30  15
2000 7   60  30
     8   40  20
2001 9   50  25
```

Another solutions:

If use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) or [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) then are added all missing datetimes between (what should be nice or not):

```
print(df.resample('MS', on='Date').sum())
```

---

```
print(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='Date')).sum())
```

Or convert datetimes to month periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
print(df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.to_period('m')).sum())
          X   Y
Date           
1999-02  30  15
1999-10  30  15
2000-07  60  30
2000-08  40  20
2001-09  50  25
```

Comment: is it possible to have the sum in another column, and have the sum repeated for values of the same group? What I mean by that is, the original table has 6 entries of which 3 entries are for October 1999. So instead of having 80 (10+20+50) as a grouped value. Have 80 repeated for each entry of october 1999. I am asking this since I want to follow your logic to calculate the Z score. I am planning to do that by calculating the mean and standard deviation separately and then computing the z score for each entry. However, I am unable to that when the tables have different dimensions

Comment: (EQ1:) mean_df = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.year.rename('y'), df['Date'].dt.month.rename('m')]).mean() ;                                                        
(EQ2:) std_df = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.year.rename('y'), df['Date'].dt.month.rename('m')]).std();                                                       
(EQ3:) df['z_sco'] = (df['X'] - mean_df['X']) / std_df['X']

Comment: @imantha check transform from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907933/2901002)

Comment: @imantha I am on phone only, so not tested `mean_df = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.year.rename('y'), df['Date'].dt.month.rename('m')])transform('mean') ; (EQ2:) std_df = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.year.rename('y'), df['Date'].dt.month.rename('m')]).transform('std'); (EQ3:) df['z_sco'] = (df['X'] - mean_df) / std_df `

Comment: tried it and it works. Thanks, heaps, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.assign(yr = df['Date'].dt.year, mnth = df['Date'].dt.month).groupby(['yr', 'mnth']).sum()

    Out[1]:

            X   Y
yr  mnth        
1999    2   30  15
        10  30  15
2000    7   60  30
        8   40  20
2001    9   50  25
```